# How Can I remove pine script file?

Tags: pine-script-v5

I am Begginer in pine script and  test many Project pine script of trading view.
how can delete some of projected  made in trading view pine script?

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Indicators", then "My scripts". Place your mouse cursor above the script that you want to delete, but do *not* click on it; at its right, a "x" sign will appear. Click on it and this will delete the script.